# MacOS append char at end of line with sed

Tags: sed, macos, newlines

I'm on MacOS where I want to enclose field names by "" in the header. Reading the file with sed, I use this command

```
sed -i.bkp -e '1s/,/","/g' -e '1s/.*/"&/g' -e '1s/.*/&"/g' myfile.csv
```

Running the command above, I get `"﻿field1","field2","fieldN "`.
It's not well represented here but there is a space between the 1st " and field1 and fieldN is followed by CRLF.

What's going wrong ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of the input file and the output you would want from that example so we can test our answers. Also, the CSV format allows for things like `"field1 part1, field1 part2"`, do we need to handle those or can you be sure there will never be internal `,` in the same field? How about internal line breaks, also allowed by CSV?

Comment: That said, although I would need the example to be sure, I suspect you don't want ` -e '1s/.*/"&/g' -e '1s/.*/&"/g'` twice, you certainly don't want the `g` there and you probably just need `sed -i.bkp -e '1s/,/","/g' -e '1s/$/"/' myfile.csv`

Comment: Do you know the line ending of the input file (Unix, DOS or Mac)? And what is the desired line ending of the output file? It seems you have DOS line endings and need to keep them, so you need to add the `"` *before*  the CR (which is part of the line from `sed`''s perspective. So do `sed '1s/,/","/g;1s/^/"/;1s/[[:cntrl:]]*$/"&/'`

Comment: Thanks @Philippos. Your command is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to a Windows formatted file (CRLF). I openned it into an editor, converted in Unix format, saved it.
Now the command works fine